# Multivariate conditional entropy

Tags: information-theory

I would like to take data columns and compute the multivariate conditional entropy.  For instance, suppose I have columns $A, B, C D, E$ and I want to compute the conditional entropy $H(E | A,B,C,D)$.  Can someone give a little explanation of all this, pointing out the first joint variable $A,B,C,D$ vs the second variable $E$.  Then please give the algorithm and math for calculating the conditional entropy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> suppose I have columns A,B,C,D,E

If by "columns" you mean random variables, for which you know the joint (five dimensional) probability function, then to compute $H(E | A,B,C,D)$  you just use the common defition of conditional entropy

$$H(X | Y) = \sum_Y P(Y=y) H(X | Y=y)$$

replacing $X$ by $E$ and $Y$ by your (multivariate) variable $(A,B,C,D)$.

Comment: Yes, I think random variable is the same as a data column.